# How to add device plug in sound in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: sound, indicator-sound, sound-theme

as you know in windows when *we plug something* theres a **tune** that plays
how can i add one in my ubuntu machine?
v20.04
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I already have this bash script in my Ubuntu 18.04, not very cleaner but it works properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -rm /dev/disk/by-label/ -e CREATE -e DELETE | while read path action file; do
if [ $action = CREATE ]; then
   dev=$(ls -lt1 /dev/disk/by-label/ | grep -o "sd[b-z][0-9]" | head -n1)
   size=$(lsblk | grep $dev | awk '{print $4}')

   aplay path/to/the/file1.wav &
   notify-send "$file"  "Device $size pluggued"
else
   aplay path/to/the/file2.wav &
   notify-send "$file"  "Device unpluggued"
fi
done &
exit
```

Add it to the startup applications and you'll have a sound and notification alert on every device plug.
Hope this help you.